# Find NetBIOS/WINS name of a IP

Tags: windows, networking, netbios

How can I find the NetBIOS/WINS name of a PC in my LAN

In suma:
I have the IP of a machine in my LAN
I want to get the name of the machine (if it has one)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### How can I find the NetBIOS/WINS name of a PC

You can use `nbtstat`

Example:

```
nbtstat -A x.x.x.x
```

> **Syntax**
>
> ...
>
> By IP address
>
> ```
>   NBTSTAT -A IP_address [options] [interval]
> ```
>
> **Key**
>
> ...
>
> `-A`   (Adapter status) List the remote machine's name table given its
> IP address

Source [NBTSTAT.exe - Display protocol statistics and current TCP/IP connections using NBT (NetBIOS over TCP/IP)](http://ss64.com/nt/nbtstat.html)

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: On Linux, it's `smbutil -v status -ae IP`.

Answer (score 7):

**`ping -a` `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`**

This will try `WINS` and then `DNS`.

The `NSLOOKUP` command does similar, but only via `DNS`.

Comment: thanks,,, but sadly ping -a <ip> is not reveling the netBIOS name (and I know the name exists (if i ping the pc by name works ok)

Comment: No DNS in this LAN (by option)

Comment: Are you happy to download a third party tool to achieve your goal?

Comment: I use several 3rd party tools... like netscan, to achieve this... I was wondering if this could be done with OS tools... THX!

Answer (score 0):

From a Windows system :

`nbtstat  -A x.x.x.x`

From Linux a Linux :

`nmblookup -A x.x.x.x`